# Overflowing child div inside parent is expanding parent

Tags: html, css, overflow, testimonials

I'm having this issue with a div for comments overflowing it's parent .. I've been trying a couple options in CSS but no success.

[image: example]

```
<div class="col-md-8 depos>
  <div class="col-md-7 depo-cont>
    <div class="depo">
      <h5>Marcio</h5>
      <p>Vou de novo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-5">Form here</div>
</div>
```

Main problem is trying to overflow the "depo-cont" div expands the bottom of the parent. Any ideas on how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it setting the child element's max-height to be the same as the parent ( which naturally causes overflow once content exceeds the size. )

```
.depo-cont{
max-height:500px;
overflow:scroll;}
```

[image: fix]

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to have a fixed height on the `.depos` container, then you could tell it to scroll its content when it becomes too tall:

```
.depos {overflow: scroll;}
```

Simple demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.outer {height: 200px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, et, officiis, molestiae, ea veniam esse nam enim eaque ad tenetur cum incidunt consectetur iste ullam eos veritatis cupiditate tempora consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, et, officiis, molestiae, ea veniam esse nam enim eaque ad tenetur cum incidunt consectetur iste ullam eos veritatis cupiditate tempora consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it is increasing the height of the div containing the form aswell ! I need a fixed height for both and only the depos scrolling